# EDL is non-functional and /data partition is inaccessible, and I fear that my Android device is permanently damaged

Tags: boot-loop, storage, partitions, data

I have a `OnePlus 7Pro (GM1917)` that was working fine for a long time with `OOS 10.3.8`. Its bootloader is unlocked, and it was rooted. I hadn't upgraded it for a long time, and recently I decided to flash an A11 ROM: `OOS 11.0.5.1.GM21AA`. At that point, I lost all ability to access the `/data` partition.

I know that there can be similar issues with such an A10-to-A11 upgrade, and that many of these issues are solvable. However, I have investigated and tried many things to fix this, to no avail, and I fear that my problem goes deeper than those issues and might not be fixable. But I'm hoping that there might still be something which I haven't tried that could fix my problem.

Here is a detailed description of everything I did, how it all failed, and everything I have tried so far to fix it ...

After the A10-to-A11 upgrade, my device went into a permanent boot loop when trying to boot to `System`.

I then did `fastboot boot twrp-3.6.0_11-0-guacamole.img` (which is the version of TWRP that is meant to work with this `OOS 11.0.5.1` ROM), and this indeed put me into TWRP. However, the `/data` partition is inaccessible. Whenever I try to format `/data`, I consistently get these messages:

```
Failed to mount /data (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
Unable to mount storage
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
Unable to wipe data
```

I then went back to the bootloader, and I ran these commands:

```
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot format:ext4 userdata
```

These commands successfully run with no error messages. However, when I then go back into TWRP, `/data` is still inaccessible, and I get the same error messages that I listed above when trying to format `/data` .

I then tried to decrypt `/data`, but when I do so, it asks for a password, and I have no idea what password to give. I never used any password on the device in the past. I am not allowed to decrypt `/data` without a password.

So, I decided to use the `MsmDownloadTool` to reflash my device back to `OOS 10.3.8`. This works fine with a different `GM1917` device that I have (but which I never tried flashing to `OOS 11`). However, with this particular device, after going into `EDL` mode, I am told that I am "Connected", but a couple seconds later it gives me the "Sahara Connection Failed" message. I have double-, triple-, and quadruple-checked the device drivers, and it indeed is showing that the `Qualcomm qds 9008` driver is properly installed and active on the PC. Furthermore, as I mentioned, I have no problem using `MsmDownloadTool` on that same PC with another `GM1917` device.

I then went further: I extracted `payload.bin` from the `OOS 11.0.5.1.GM21AA` installation bundle, and I extracted all of the `*.img` files. I flashed `boot.img` via fastboot and retried everything that I mentioned above, but nothing has changed.

I then went and flashed all of the `*.img` files via fastboot. However, still nothing has changed.

When flashing the set of all `*.img` files, in some cases, I was told that the file is critical and cannot be reflashed. I then ran these two commands ...

```
fastboot flashing unlock
fastboot flashing unlock_critical
```

... but in both cases, I am told that the device is already unlocked. Trying to flash all of the `*.img` files again gave me the same results: *i.e.*, some got flashed, and others were not flashed due to being "Critical".

Also, some of the items I flashed were said to be "sparse", and their flashes were flagged with warnings, but as far as I can tell, they seem to have been flashed anyway.

In the end, I still go into a bootloop when booting to `System`, the `/data` partition is still inaccessible, and `EDL` mode still does not function.

Do these problems with `/data` and `EDL` and everything else mean that my device is somehow permanently damaged? Or are there perhaps one or more additional things that I can try in order to restore it to some sort of working state?

Thank you in advance for any thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `/data` has now been fixed.

I had forgotten that in the past, I was trying the `OrangeFox` dual-boot recovery on this device, and it had repartitioned `/data`.

I fixed this by flashing the appropriate `*.img` files again for my OS (OOS 10.3.8), and then by booting into the standard OrangeFox recovery (the non-dual-boot version) via fastboot, and then by using its `adb sideload` facility to flash that same OrangeFox recovery. OrangeFox's `adb sideload` mechanism offers options to the user for repartitioning and rebuilding `/data`. I utilized those options and set `/data` back to "Stock", and after that, `/data` became accessible again, and I could format it and access it in recovery with no problem.

At this point, I flashed `OOS 10.3.8`, and I then flashed the appropriate TWRP and Magisk. Now, my device is back up and running in that OOS version.

The `EDL` problem continues, but given that my device is now usable again, I am not overly concerned about this `MsmDownloadTool` issue at the moment. In my spare time, I'll continue to look into that.

All's well that ends well! ... and now it's indeed a happy New Year for me!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a perfect answer for you, I can at least provide some info on `MSMDownloadTool`. I've resolved that `Sahara Connection Failed` issue through a couple of ways:

- Changing the USB port I am connected to
- Reattaching my device
- Restarting the program

`MSMDownloadTool` seems pretty finicky. I usually get stuck in a loop where it completes and then restarts the flash, locking my phone into EDL mode. I'd recommend flashing via `fastboot` or `recovery` before resorting to `MSMDownloadTool`. I've had some luck directly flashing the OTA Updates that OnePlus provides.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I tried those same things numerous times with MsmDownloadTool, and unfortunately, that problem persists. However, I managed to fix the problem with /data!  See my Answer, which I am now posting.